# SSRS change bullet color

Tags: reporting-services, colors, listitem, bullet, ssrs-2019

I've been request to change the color of the list item from black to red (our company logo color, our branding) in SSRS.
I've tried to replace the the

by my own bullet colored and changed the placeholder in HTML mode :

```
=REPLACE(
REPLACE(
    First(Fields!Description.Value, "myDatasetName")
    , "<li>"
    , "<font color='#E61E3C'>•</font>     "
)
, "</li>"
, "<br/>"
)
```

My bullet is now in red so that's cool....however I've lost the property of a list :

- my long 
  text should appear like this

So to have the text of the next rows being aligned with the first text row. However, as expected, the text is aligned with the bullet. My approach is wrong as it should remain a list item to benefit of all the properties.

[With CSS we can change the color](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bullet_color.asp), does anyone know how we can do it in SSRS ?

Any help would be appreciated.

SQL Server version : 2019

Comment: open the RDL and do a search/replace. If you put all the RDL files in a folder you could use Visual Studio Code (free) to update all the RDL files at once. Then redploy the reports

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the link between my demand and a search/replace. Can you describe your idea ? I want to change the color of the bullet that is automatically generated by SSRS in HTML mode when reading a HTML text containing <ul><li>

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is that I've developed my own list subreport.
This sub report is a tablix with 3 columns :

- the bullet (in red)
- a column representing spaces between bullet and content
- the text content (in my case it's a title in uppercase + newline + a content)

I can then change the :

- list style type (bullet, number, hyphen,..)
- the color
- the size of the list style
- ...
  ...as I want

I've changed by SQL query to return a list of records. My report has a tablix that calls my own list subReport having the necessary parameters (textItem,...)